# (File Explorer) Classes in python: logic of instance attributes inside __init__ or inside it's own method?

Tags: python, class, oop, instance, explorer

++++++++++++ Intro ++++++++++++
Hello there. This is my first python program. A Windows-like File Explorer, that filters for media, and creates thumbnails(100x100), where I can select multiple files to feed to a different program, for processing. Also ability to scroll works like a charm...more to come.(Folder icons. etc) Works pretty good so far. 3 seconds to load and show 100 images.(Thumbnail cache not yet implemented)
Originally I just wanted to do a listbox(textbased) to feed to other python programs,..well I guess it got a bit more complicated :) Right until now I used many global variables, but I want to get into good programming habits, watched a few tutorials on classes, and now I am rearranging everything into classes.(Hope this is not too much intro text, my first post here)
+++++++++++ Intro End +++++++++

Basically my Class(Folder) has:
+directory
+list of filtered Media(which is actually what is used to display in the file explorer)
attributes of that filtered media like:
-element name(Filename)
-thumbnail Image
-is selected(bool)
-type(Media, folder, etc, not yet implemented)

I have made two working solutions:

Solution #1:
Basically everything gets initialized inside a method.

```
class Folder:
    def __init__(self, directory):
        self.directory = directory
        self.elements_create(directory)

    def elements_create(self, directory):
        self.element_name = []
        self.element_image_data = []
        self.element_is_selected = []
        self.element_is_type = []
        for file in os.listdir(directory):
            if file.endswith((".gif", ".png", ".jpg")):
                self.element_name.append(file)
                self.element_is_selected.append(False)
                try:
                    self.element_image_data.append(
                        image.convert_to_bytes(os.path.join(directory, file), (100, 100), fill_blanc_color=True))
                except:
                    sg.popup(f"Error reading Image:{self.element_name}")
                    self.element_image_data.append(empty_image)

    def shortname(self, key):
        start_slice = len(self.element_name[key]) - config_filename_formatting[0]
        return self.element_name[key][start_slice if start_slice > 0 else 0:]
```

In solution #1: Every time I change the folder(or later implementation: a file gets changed)
I just call elements_create and set a new directory.

Solution #2:
Basically everything gets initialised inside the **init**(sounds logical..lol)

```
class Folder:
    def __init__(self, directory):
        self.directory = directory
        self.element_list = []
        self.element_image_data = []
        self.element_is_selected = []
        self.element_is_type = []
            for file in os.listdir(directory):
                if file.endswith((".gif", ".png", ".jpg")):
                    self.element_list.append(file)
                    self.element_is_selected.append(False)
                    try:
                        self.element_image_data.append(
                            image.convert_to_bytes(os.path.join(directory, file), (100, 100), fill_blanc_color=True))
                    except:
                        sg.popup(f"Error reading Image:{self.element_list}")
                        self.element_image_data.append(empty_image)

    def shortname(self, key):
        start_slice = len(self.element_list[key]) - config_filename_formatting[0]
        return self.element_list[key][start_slice if start_slice > 0 else 0:]
```

In solution #2: Every time I change the folder(or later implementation: a file gets changed)
I just overwrite the instance, by creating a new one with the same name.

Question 1:)Which solution is better and why? Is there even much of a difference?

OPTIONAL QUESTIONS:
Question 2:)later I maybe want to implement much more, like Folder Icons, deleting, etc.
Is a different structure better suited?

All the elements which are drawn on the screen, are accessed by their index(count):
I just calculate the indexposition(count)
The dummyframes are accessed with a tuple(x, y)

```
def images_draw():
    count = 0
    count = count + (int(slider_pos) * config_columnsize)

    for row_index in range(config_rowsize):
        for column_index in range(config_columnsize):
            if count >= len(folder_left.element_name):
                window[(row_index, column_index)].update(data=empty_image, visible=False)
                window["Text", (row_index, column_index)].update('')
                window["Frame", (row_index, column_index)].Widget.config(background='#64778d', pady=2, padx=2)
            else:
                window[(row_index, column_index)].update(data=(folder_left.element_image_data[count]), visible=True)
                window["Text", (row_index, column_index)].update(folder_left.shortname(count))
                if folder_left.element_is_selected[count]:
                    window["Frame", (row_index, column_index)].Widget.config(background='#c3ca02', pady=2, padx=2) #selected
                else:
                    window["Frame", (row_index, column_index)].Widget.config(background='#64778d', pady=2, padx=2) #not selected
            count += 1
```

Question 3:)
Should I create a EXTRA list?/Dictionary?/Class? with all the elements visible on the screen,
[maybe as key a (x ,y) tuple] like my dummy Frames, or is working with calculating the index like:

```
x, y = event
index_position = int((x + slider_pos) * config_columnsize) + y
```

a valid solution?
I see no need for that extra, but maybe later debugging gets easier with more functions.

As already mentioned....multyselection and scrolling are working fine.
Keep in mind I wanna do folders and deleting and possible other stuff later.
But I think manipulating the Class Folder with a method(example delete element), seems a reasonable approach.

Question 4:) I often saw getter methods for Class elements in other code.
Why is it considered bad practice to read it directly?
I get why changing a Class element directly could be bad.

Later I want put the other variables also in classes as a next step, like column_size, row_size.
Hope this was not too much text, and I wanna get into got habits, and start a coding career down the line. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question currently includes multiple questions in one and includes opinion-based questions. It should focus on one problem and include enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hey Alex. Well I did read that. I also wrote in Big letters OPTIONAL QUESTIONS in front questions 2-4, which were more opinion based.
But Question one was pretty straight forward I thought.
I presented two working code samples, and was wondering which one is "best practice", OR/AND if there is even a difference.  Should I edit, delete question 2-4 and make my question more clear?